# Override third party class method inside CakePHP model

Tags: php, cakephp

I am starting a new project which involves scraping websites and so am planning on using PHPCrawl http://cuab.de/quickstart.html as it looks like the best PHP based solution for this (unless anybody has any other suggestions) but have run into a problem that I can't quite get my head around.

So I import the PHPCrawl class with

```
App::import('Vendor', 'PHPCrawl', array('file' => 'PHPCrawl/libs/PHPCrawler.class.php'));
```

Then just underneath that I extend the PHPCrawl class to handle the data like so

```
class MyCrawler extends PHPCrawler{
    function handleDocumentInfo($DocInfo) {
        //handle data here
    }
}
```

But my problem comes in when I need to perform CakePHP methods like create() and save() from within that method. I tried creating a new instance of the CakePHP model within the class but that gives me a warning:

```
Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!
```

So I assume that this is creating an infinite loop of class instances. I guess what I want to do is override the handleDocumentInfo() function but within my CakePHP class, is that possible?

Apologies if this isn't clear, I don't quite know how to go about this one!

Answer (score 0):

For anybody having a similar problem. I got around this by creating a component, importing the class and overriding the method inside that. Had to mess with the original class a little and add a new global var but all seems to be working